# Is it possible to check scrolls down reach the end if iframe src is online url pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Try to add iframe src for an iframe using online pdf url.

But is it possible to check if online pdf is scrolls down and reach the end (not HTML) ?
Because if i try to print contentDocument, it's return null

**HTML**

```
 <iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame" class="scroll-y overlay" style="height:300px;"></iframe> 
    
   <label style="cursor:pointer;">
       <input type="checkbox" id="chkTermAndCondition" disabled 
        onchange="handleChange(this);" />
        Approve S and K.
    </label>
```

**JS**

```
$("#myFrame").attr("src","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/GeneralBiology.pdf");
        $("#myFrame").load(function () {
            //console.log("myFrame load function");
            var win_iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow;
            var doc_iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame').contentDocument;


            $(win_iframe).on("scroll", function() {
                if ((win_iframe.innerHeight + win_iframe.scrollY) >= doc_iframe.body.offsetHeight) {
                //console.log("aaa..! works perfectly!");
                $("#chkTermAndCondition").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: You don't get access to iframe content that was loaded from a different origin.

Comment: If i chmod the file, is it possible to get content? @CBroe. Or is there any way to implement the url to local content so it cant be modified?